# How to send data from .cs to HTML5

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8.1, html5-canvas

I am trying to invoke my windows workflow web service from `Azure` into my `HTML5` mobile application. I m using C# to consume the web service and I would like to send the data to my `HTML` page. Using the code as below:

```
private void Client_GetDataFromWorkflowCompleted(object sender, GetDataFromWorkflowCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> resultval = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();

            resultval = e.Result;
             MainUri = "/Html/index.html?" + "a=" + resultval[1] + "&b=" + resultval[2] + "&c=" + resultval[3] + "&d=" + resultval[4]  ;
          //  var myUri = new Uri("/Html/index.html?a=" + Uri.EscapeDataString((string)resultval[1]), UriKind.Relative);

         //   Uri a = new Uri();
            Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

When i do this i get error at my emulator unable to navigate to this page.

This is my call function:

```
MapWorkflow.ServiceClient client = new MapWorkflow.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService");
            client.GetDataFromWorkflowCompleted += Client_GetDataFromWorkflowCompleted;
            client.GetDataFromWorkflowAsync();
```

I m using a web service from windows workflow : 
http://updatemapfether.azurewebsites.net/Service1.xamlx?singleWsdl

I have tried calling using J query but it don't seem to work. so i manage to call the web service thru my c# code i am unable to send the data to my HTML page.

My HTML page contains a map which suppose to display the data from this web service.

Comment: I am struggling to see what your issue is - for instance; can you post an example of the resulting URL ? Also; have you used Fiddler on your development environment to view the actual HTTP traffic to see what the underlying HTTP request/response traffic is ?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please do check

Answer (score 0):

You should send an ajax request to your webservice to get data instead of your webservice send something to your html.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

Comment: tried with jQuery but unable to invoke this web service: http://updatemapfether.azurewebsites.net/Service1.xamlx?singleWsdl